# How do I earn more Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-duel

I played the game quite a bit yesterday, and won a bunch of matches. Then I got to a point where I really couldn't win anymore, since everybody seemed to have much better Pokémon than me.  I have the ones I started with, plus two that came from unlocking the timed boxes.  It seems as though most of the people I duel, have tons of awesome Pokémon!

What am I doing wrong? Why am I not earning gems, coins, or Pokémon? Do I have to pay real money?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a button on the right hand side that is 6 little squares arranged in two rows of three, this is where the Messages, Daily Missions, Rankings, Records, Room Match, Featured Duel, and Quests options are. It is referred to as the Options button below.

You should be getting gems for logging in, as well as playing the single player missions, which can be found under Options - Quests. You should also be claiming something from your daily missions.

- Multiplayer (the big Play button) gives timed and locked boosters with figures and other rewards
- Single player storyline (Options - Quests) gives gems, coins, and figures

  - Rewards must be retrieved from Options - Messages
- Daily log in bonuses from Options - Messages
- Daily missions are listed and claimed from Options - Daily Missions
- Material Exchange in the Shop will let you buy figures with yet another currency: Material
- Special Gym Cups show as a button in the top left hand corner. There are rewards (gems, ingots, rare metals, cubes...) for overall wins, as well as gym boosters for win streaks.

Comment: That's the problem... I was just clicking the big Play button. I din't realize there was a "story" mode. Thank you.

Comment: Each story mode mission also has some bonus goals, such as win within 50 moves, get all of your figures off your bench before winning, use a purple attack, win two fights. Those bonuses are claimed from the Menu - Messages interface, usually a handful of gems.